# If $f'(x)\geq 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $f$ is twice differentiable which of the following is true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For every function f:[0,1] $\to\mathbb{R}$ which is twice differentiable and satisfies $f'(x)\geq 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, we must have

a)$f''(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$

b) $f(x)\geq x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$

c) $f(x_2)-x_2\leq f(x_1)-x_1$ for all $x_1,x_2\in[0,1]$ with $x_2\geq x_1$

d) $f(x_2)-x_2\geq f(x_1)-x_1$ for all $x_1,x_2\in[0,1]$ with $x_2\geq x_1$

My thoughts: If we take $f(x)=ax+b$ and $f(x)=e^{ax}$ with $a>1$, option (a) is correct, option (b) won't work for $b<0$, so (b) is not true. Option (d) is correct.

So, how do I confirm further between (a) and (d) ? What is a proper way to solve this (rather than case-by-case check) ?

Comment: What do you think of $(x-\frac{1}{2})^3$ for your a)?

Comment: With examples you can only show that one of the statements is wrong, not that it is correct, since it should hold for *all* functions satisfying the stated condition.

Comment: Thanks .. but is there a proper way to solve this (rather than case-by-case check) ?

Comment: @square_one Well in this type of question you can't really solve it directly unless you were to find every property this family of functions will have which I think is a tad too difficult(and I doubt whether one can come up with an exhaustive list)

Comment: so case-by-case check is the only way here ?

Comment: @square_one yes, you've to check every option here.

Comment: Hint: the mean value theorem is useful here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of (d)

Using Lagrange's Mean Value Thm -

$\frac{ f(x_2)- f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} = f'(c) $ where $x \in (x_1,x_2) \implies c \in [0,1]$

Now, $f'(x) \geq 1 \forall x \in [0,1]$

Thus $f'(c)\geq 1$

And you get (d )after some trivial manipulations .

Answer (score 0):

a) $f(x)=4 \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{2} } $

b) $ f(x)=x-1 $

c) $ f(x) = 2x $